# In javascript, is there a way to distinguish letters from other characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I want to replace "you" with "your sister". However a word like "youtube" must remain unchanged. So i decided to use

```
replace(/ you /, " your sister ");
```

However now the string "I love you!" remains unchanged, as well as any string where the word you is not followed by a string with a space in it. I would like to know if the character that follows the word "you" is a letter or not. If it is, leave it unchanged, if it is not, change it to "your sister".

Comment: str.replace(" you ", "your sister");

Comment: @torazaburo they're probably also looking for a useful link or full answer on how to use that, given that `\b` only means something when used in a real regular expression call =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's a "letter"? This is not as dumb a question as it might sound seem at a casual glance: for example, many languages treat `7` as a number, but there are orthographies (such as [Squamish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squamish_language)) in which it's actually a letter. So in this case you need to more precisely describe what you mean so that answers can be tailored to that (you did a good job at that, but your title's still suggestive).

To answer the actual question, you can do a global regular expression replacement such as:

```
const replaced = input.replace(/\byou\b/g, 'your sister');
```

Using this, the string "you" will be replaced by the string "your sister", but only if it's surrounded by "word boundaries" (spaces, start/end of sentence, symbols, etc).

We also need to use the `/.../g` modifier (for 'global matching') so that the replacement acts on *all* instances of "you", rather than just the first.

Answer (score 4):

You need word boundary character `\b`

```
s.replace(/\byou\b/g, 'your sister')
```

Comment: although probably with a `g` modifier

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `\b` (word boundary):

```
slice(/\byou\b/, "your sister")
```

But what is `slice`? I assume you mean something like

```
string.replace(/\byou\b/, "your sister")
```

Answer (score 2):

`\b` matches a word boundary – between a word character (actually alphanumeric plus underscore<sup>1</sup>) and a non-word character.

So `/\byou\b/` would match "you" when not part of another word.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is for "historical reasons": it made it easy to match the usual set of characters allowed in C like programming language identifiers.